# Complex(repeating) rule using Spacy Pattern Matcher

Tags: python, spacy, matcher

I want to match a repeating pattern using spaCy's pattern matcher. Following is the pattern that i want to match:
`My account number is: 2893-26492-634-0924-63. Some more text here.`
Basically, trying to match the following regex: `\d+(-\d+)*`

```py
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add('NUMBER_MERGE', None, [ {'IS_DIGIT': True}, {'IS_PUNCT': True}, {'IS_DIGIT': True}, {'IS_SPACE':True}])
```

This matches `342-234 Text`, however fails for `342-234-958 Text`.

I did not find any documentation to apply quantifiers on a set of operators. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly use the regex as a pattern.

```
matcher.add('NUMBER_MERGE', None, [{"TEXT": {"REGEX": "\d+(-\d+)*"}}])
```